borders should be placed in every corner and dashed border lines shoul be controllable
borders should be placed in every corner i used https://kovart.github.io but it didn't work please help
border lines should be rounded and fixed as an example below
Border dashed

You need to background-image, here is an example


h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.block {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg width='100%25' height='100%25' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='none' rx='8' ry='8' stroke='%23333' stroke-width='2' stroke-dasharray='6%2c 14' stroke-dashoffset='22' stroke-linecap='square'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a simple HTML + CSS template!</h1>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </body>
</html>



